# Struggling with writing the diagram mathematically

Tags: permutations

> There are $5$ chemistry and $4$ physics books. How many ways can these books be arranged in a manner that physics and chemistry books will be among themselves?

By visualizing what question wants me to do, I drew a diagram as illustrated below. Recall $C$ chemistry book, $P$ physics book.

$$C_{1}C_{2}C_{3}C_{4}C_{5}P_{1}P_{2}P_{3}P_{4}$$

It seems to be enough to solve the question. However, how do I rewrite it mathematically now?

Comment: Could I ask why my question has been downvoted?

Comment: Considering all the books different, the answer is 9!

Comment: Question is not quite clear. As ab123 says, for 9 different books there are 9! arrangements. I suspect though that the question only wants you to differentiate between Chemistry and Physics, so more like CCCCCPPPP being one arrangement.

Comment: I didn't mean that. The question wants me to determine it in a manner that Physics and Chemistry books will be among themselves. For instance, you cannot do CCCPCPPPC

Comment: $2\cdot 4!\cdot 5! =5760$